# How to get MongoDB data according to returned IdObject within same page in Flask?

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

I'm using dropdownMenu of Bootstrap where each item in the menu gets an IdObject of my MongoDB.

The reason is I want to have those IdObjects in one list in order to get all the data that is stored in that collection.

I could get the IdObjects and they are already in dropdownMenu. However, I'm not able to display the data according the selected IdObject.

My codes are the following:

**Python**

```py
@app.route("/get_object", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_object():
    row = []
    cursor = object_collection.find({}, {"_id": 1})
    for document in cursor:
        row.append(document['_id'])
    return render_template("get_object.html", rows=row)


@app.route("/action_get", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def action_get():
    key = request.values.get("key")
    row = object_collection.find({key})
    return render_template("objects.html", rows=row)
```

The function `get_object()` get the IdObjects. I created another function `action_get()` that is responsible to display data of a single IdObject.

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" action="/get_object">
            <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
            ID object = <input name="input_id"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark align-content-center">Get the object</button><br><br>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                {% for row in rows %}
                    <button name="key" class="dropdown-item" type="submit"><a class="dropdown-item" href="./get_object?_id={{row}}">{{row}}</a></button>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <table class="table table-hover" method="GET" action="/action_get" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>X</th>
            <th>Y</th>
            <th>Z</th>
            <th>Width</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Depth</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
           {% for row in rows %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="_id">{{row["_id"]}}</td>
                    <th>{{row["x_input"]}}</th>
                    <th>{{row["y_input"]}}</th>
                    <th>{{row["z_input"]}}</th>
                    <th>{{row["w_input"]}}</th>
                    <th>{{row["h_input"]}}</th>
                    <th>{{row["d_input"]}}</th>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

However, the display thing is not working. I think I have missed something which I couldn't know where.

Comment: What is `key`? It's very unlikely you actually want that, and probably just want `find({ "_id": key })` if `key` is the value of `_id`. You probably really want to convert that to an `ObjectId` since it's probably just a string.

Comment: @NeilLunn `<button name="key" class="dropdown-item" type="submit"><a class="dropdown-item" href="./get_object?_id={{row}}">{{row}}</a></button>`

Comment: Yes those would now be "strings". See the linked answers showing how to import the `ObjectId` function from pymongo and use it.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I got it, Thanks! However, it didn't work, I tried to show a message at `action_get()` and didn't show anything. Obviously, something wrong in the HTML. How can it be fixed?